# How to locate the default value constraint for a column name

Tags: sql, t-sql, constraints

I noticed that some date columns in a database table are giving my Power App a hard time ( patching) when the default value is '0001-01-01' and the no valid date is supplied.  Note I can't just set default values in my Power App as the SQL Table is used by other applications.

My current thinking is I change the default value say to '1001-01-01' using TSQL so that I can automate it as much as possible.

1. Get the (DF_TABLENAME_XXXX) constraint name for the column and say shove it into a variable @mytablename
2. Drop this constraint name
3. Recreate the constraint with
   `ALTER TABLE @MyTable  DEFAULT '1001-12-31' FOR @ColumnName`

I am struggling with step 1) atm . Also I am happy to adopt a better approach than the one I have outlined.

Comment: You can find all the default constraints listed in `sys.default_constraints`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code sometime ago to create a Data Dictionary of sorts. It uses all the sys tables to grab information about the tables in your database. Just change the top line and you should be all set.

```
USE [INSERT YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE]
GO

SELECT
            DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName]
            , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(TBL.[object_id],DB_ID()) AS [Schema]
            , TBL.[name] AS [TableName]
            , AC.[name] AS [ColumnName]
            , UPPER(TY.[name]) AS [DataType]
            , AC.[max_length] AS [Length]
            , AC.[precision] AS [Precision]
            , AC.[scale] AS [Scale]
            , AC.[is_nullable] AS [IsNullable]
            , ISNULL(SI.is_primary_key,0) AS [IsPrimaryKey]
            , SKC.name AS [PrimaryKeyConstarint]

            , CASE
                    WHEN SIC.index_column_id > 0
                            THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END AS [IsIndexed]

            , ISNULL(is_included_column, 0) AS [IsIncludedIndex]
            , SI.name AS [IndexName]
            , OBJECT_NAME(SFC.constraint_object_id) AS [ForeignKeyConstraint]
            , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(TBL_PRIM.[object_id],DB_ID()) AS [ParentTableSchema]
            , OBJECT_NAME(SFC.referenced_object_id) AS [ParentTableName]
            , COL_PRIM.name AS [ParentTableColumnName]

            , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(TBL.[object_id],DB_ID()) + '.' + TBL.[name] + '.' + AC.[name]
                + ' = ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(TBL_PRIM.[object_id],DB_ID()) + '.'
                + OBJECT_NAME(SFC.referenced_object_id) + '.' + COL_PRIM.name AS [JoinCondition]

            , SDC.name AS [DefaultConstraint]
            , SDC.[definition] AS [DefaultValue]
            , AC.collation_name AS [Collation]
            , SEP.value AS [Comments]

FROM [sys].[tables] AS TBL

JOIN [sys].[all_columns] AS AC
        ON TBL.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]

JOIN [sys].[types] AS TY
        ON AC.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id]
        AND AC.[user_type_id] = TY.[user_type_id]

LEFT JOIN [sys].[index_columns] AS SIC
        ON sic.[object_id] = TBL.[object_id]
        AND AC.column_id = SIC.column_id

LEFT JOIN [sys].[indexes] AS SI
        ON SI.[object_id] = TBL.[object_id]
        AND SIC.index_id = SI.index_id

LEFT JOIN [sys].[foreign_key_columns] AS SFC
        ON SFC.parent_object_id = TBL.[object_id]
        AND SFC.parent_column_id = AC.column_id

LEFT JOIN [sys].[key_constraints] AS SKC
        ON skc.parent_object_id = TBL.[object_id]
        AND SIC.index_column_id = SKC.unique_index_id

LEFT JOIN [sys].[default_constraints] AS SDC
        ON SDC.parent_column_id = AC.column_id

LEFT JOIN [sys].[extended_properties] AS SEP
        ON SEP.major_id = TBL.[object_id]
        AND SEP.minor_id = AC.column_id

LEFT JOIN [sys].[tables] AS TBL_PRIM
        ON SFC.referenced_object_id = TBL_PRIM.[object_id]

LEFT JOIN [sys].[columns] AS COL_PRIM
        ON SFC.referenced_object_id = COL_PRIM.[object_id]
        AND SFC.referenced_column_id = COL_PRIM.column_id
```

Comment: Thanks for this. does produce some interesting results although when I ran it, there seemed a lot duplicate rows for the same table and column name. I can this being quite useful.

Comment: Here is my tweak`SELECT
    SchemaName = SCH.[name]
    ,TableName = TAB.[name]
    ,ColumnName = COL.[name]
    ,DefaultConstraint = DFC.[name]
INTO [#MyTable]
FROM sys.default_constraints AS DFC
    JOIN sys.columns AS COL
        ON DFC.parent_object_id = COL.[object_id]
            AND DFC.parent_column_id = COL.column_id
    JOIN sys.tables AS TAB
        ON COL.[object_id] = TAB.[object_id]
    JOIN SYS.schemas AS SCH
        ON TAB.[schema_id] = SCH.[schema_id]
WHERE SCH.[name] = 'DBO'
    AND TAB.[name] = @TableName
    AND COL.[name] = @ColumnName;`

Comment: @westerdaled if this is resolved, please accept one of the responses as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the question marks in the where clause, and this will give you the name of your default constraint.

```
SELECT
    SchemaName = SCH.[name]
    ,TableName = TAB.[name]
    ,ColumnName = COL.[name]
    ,DefaultConstraint = DFC.[name]
FROM sys.default_constraints AS DFC
    JOIN sys.columns AS COL
        ON DFC.parent_object_id = COL.[object_id]
            AND DFC.parent_column_id = COL.column_id
    JOIN sys.tables AS TAB
        ON COL.[object_id] = TAB.[object_id]
    JOIN SYS.schemas AS SCH
        ON TAB.[schema_id] = SCH.[schema_id]
WHERE SCH.[name] = ?
    AND TAB.[name] = ?
    AND COL.[name] = ?
```

Comment: Pasted this into VSCode with the SQLServer Addin and it worked like a charm. Looks like I will need to create temporary table with the results.

Comment: FWIW, I'd recommend explicitly naming your new constraints. Syntax is something like..

ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT DF_tablename_columnname DEFAULT(defaultvalue) FOR columnname

Comment: Thanks I will confer with the dev team in the morning following these updates.

Comment: Now I have amended Anthony's snippet to create the temp but I am now hitting 2 further issues. I can't set a var with my constraint name and then script the drop / recreate
DECLARE @ConstraintName SELECT DefaultConstraint FROM #MyTable. The other issue is I want list all date column constraints for all the tables.

Comment: You can use dynamic sql and construct the the statements by passing in parameters to sp_executesql . Or just eyeball it and write up a script. For the list, that's a new question and should be created as a new question.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I have now completed the work using Excec statements containing a dynamic string using variables for the ConstraintName , TableName etc.  I will have a go at sp_executesql statements and compare. Would be good to have TSQL/PowerShell statement to verify the constraint details rather than me refreshing the Table view in SQL Man Studio.